# DeSeqDataSet experimental design: column with integer values

Tags: rna-seq, deseq2

I am creating `DeSeqDataSet` and I am unsure whether I need to include the number of mice into the design formula. Basically, the samples look like this:

[image]

I have 4 different groups: `GF`, `B6`, `ET` and `Wld`. It is obvious that these should go into the design formula, but I am not sure about the mice number. Basically for each group, e.g. `GF`, there are 4 experiments with `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` mice each. When I am trying to use both `Groups` and `Mouse` columns as a design formula, `R` is telling that I need to convert `Mouse` to `factor`:

[image]

I am a bit confused about two things here: first, as I told already, should I include this `Mouse` column at all in the design formula of `DeSeqDataSet` and second, if I do need it, how to convert it to factor? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

It turned out that I was wrong in my initial assumptions: `Mouse#` really was an ‘id’ which I did not include in the design formula. There were 4 groups of 16 mice in each for 4 trials.

What concerns me also is that if I specify design formula as `~ Groups + Mouse`, the DeSeq() function starts comparing the `Mouse` but not the `Groups` which is the most interesting for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any IDs (e.g. replicate number) don't need to be included in the design formula if it's not a repeated factor in multiple samples.

In this case, you have said that mouse number is related to the number of mice used in the pool (and is a variable factor that is consistent across multiple samples), in which case it should be included in the design matrix. This would also be the case if the *same* mouse were being used for multiple RNASeq experiments. Converting an integer value to a factor is done by the `factor` method:

```
sampleTable$MiceUsed <- factor(sampleTable$MiceUsed);
```

Other examples of things that might be useful in the design formula would be sex, age, and sequencing run batch (assuming these are not consistent across samples).

With a design formula of something like `~Groups + Mouse`, it will also be comparing Groups, it's just hidden in the results. The [DESeq2 vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html#interactions) is really great at explaining what's going on, but as a quick answer you can pull out the `Groups` results with the `contrast` function. This will pull out group differences that are independent of mouse number:

```
results(dds, contrast=c("Groups", "GF", "Wld"))
```

[first value is the variable name, second value is the numerator condition, third is the denominator condition]